# Do glow plugs face fouling?

Tags: engine-design, fuel-systems

Do glow plugs face fouling? I understand that spark plugs foul on occasion, do glow plugs face the same issue?

Comment: Glow plugs are only used to aid starting of a compression-ignition engine. Once the engine is running, the glow plugs aren't used.

Comment: In most conditions, a diesel engine will start fine without glow plugs.  The glow plug controller on my car failed and I didn't replace it for over a year. The only problem was occasional difficult starting on really cold mornings.  I think you might be helped by reading some of the [basics of how diesel engines work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine).

Comment: Additionally, a glow plug does not spark.  It is a [simple electric heater coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glowplug) and is therefore not susceptible to  fouling.

Comment: In many modern diesel engines, the ECU may keep the glow plugs on until temperature, time or RPM criteria are met. This is done to reduce emissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fine wire glow plugs, vulnerable to fouling, are not used on manned aircraft.  Glow plugs in most diesel engines have massive elements where the coil is protected from being fouled.

[image]

Comment: It is worth noting that the fine wire glow plugs you mention really only have an application in model aircraft, not full-size aircraft. The theory and operation of those types of glow-plugs is substantially different than those used in diesel aircraft engines.

Comment: The glow plugs I have cut open have a single rather heavy gauge wire which is welded to the glow tube at the tip of the plug.  I believe that the tube is part of the heating element.  Typical current draws are 7 to 20 amp at 12 V and about half that at 24V for smaller, aircraft sized engines.